# How to use $_SESSION to display messages

Tags: php, html

```
if(isset($_SESSION['contactstatus'])&& $_SESSION['contactstatus']){
 echo ' <p>Your request has sent successfully.</p>';
unset($_SESSION['contactstatus']);
}
```

I want to use session to display messages after the validation of input in the form is done. How to do it or there still need to write any codes in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you have to fill the Session after pass the validation condition.

```php
session_start();

if($validationCondition){
    $_SESSION['contactstatus'] = 'Success';

}
```

Your code is all right, and you only need to print the content of Session

```php
if(isset($_SESSION['contactstatus'])&& $_SESSION['contactstatus']){
    echo ' <p>Your request has sent successfully.</p>';
    echo 'Content of your SESSION:' . $_SESSION['contactstatus'];
    unset($_SESSION['contactstatus']);
}
```

Comment: i try the code but when I enter wrong input format it will show **Your request has sent successfully** too

Comment: oh it solved . I try to adjust the place of **$_SESSION['contactstatus'] = 'Success';** then it work. Thanks!

Comment: You can add different content in your Session to check at if condition